# How to check if a big number is a square of an integer in R?

Tags: r, integer, sqrt

I want to check if the determinant of a 22x22 matrix is a square of an integer or not.

So I have

```
> det(M)
[1] 1.849688e+29
> sqrt(det(M))
[1] 4.3008e+14
```

But now I can't see the decimal digits of this number.

So, if I run

```
> options(digits=22)
> sqrt(det(M)) 
[1] 430080000000001.1875000
```

I have this result, which means that it isn't square of an integer.

So, when I use the following function

```
check.integer <- function(N){
    !length(grep("[^[:digit:]]", as.character(N)))
}
```

the result is that the number is an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `check.integer` function does not really check if something is an integer. It checks if whatever R's character representation of something happens to have a non-digit character in it. This is a pretty bad way of doing things. You want to know if something really *is* and integer and not just if it looks like one.

Besides, there is already the `is.integer` function in R.

But this may not help in your case. R will only exactly represent integers up to a certain point, which is one of the many things stored in `.Machine`. In particular:

```
.Machine$integer.max
```

If you want to check if a matrix determinant that may be larger than `.Machine$integer.max` is a square in R you can consider going to arbitrary precision. The Rmpfr package should be able to do all this for you. It lets you have arbitrary precision matrices, has its own `determinant` function, and has its own `is.whole` function.

Comment: I still have problem Neil. I know that the determinant is square of an integer but R makes a precision. But I don't know how to get rid of it.

Comment: Did you look at `.Machine$integer.max` on your system? It seems you are dealing with integers that are large than R can handle with the precision you want. That why I suggested going using a package that allows for arbitrary precision arithmetic.

Comment: Yes I see it and the determinant is much bigger than  `.Machine$integer.max` .
So, I installed the Rmpfr pacakge, but when I run its own`determinant`, I have the same problem.
The problem is the approximation that R produces while it calculates the determinant.

Comment: Neil, I used this
`determinant(x, logarithm = TRUE,
asNumeric = (d[1] > 3), precBits = max(.getPrec(x)), ...)`, which is in Rmpfr package,
to find the determinant, but I have the same problem.
Also, I can't change anything by using `is.whole`.

Comment: Neil, take a look here please:

`> a<- mpfr(det(M), precBits=128);a

1 'mpfr' number of precision  128   bits 

[1] 184968806400001015948744065024

> sqrt(a)

1 'mpfr' number of precision  128   bits 

[1] 430080000000001.1811160063999983781679912`